# WiX - Not to remove file already deployed

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I've got Application, which (in version 1) is shipping some configuration File. After deploying version 1, there was an Plugin for this application, which has overwritten the configuration file (and it is no more needed in A).

However, when we removed the File from Application's WIX package, it is being removed even if the File was overwritten by Plugin, so Plugin stops working.

Is it possible to remove the File from Application's installation (in version 2, version 1 is already released), so it isn't being shipped anymore, but the Application doesn't remove it during it's installation?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to update the original v1 package on the machine before the v1 package is uninstalled. You can do this by creating a patch (a `.msp` file) and deploying the patch to remove the file from v1 before it is uninstalled.

Note: A better design is to not have plug-ins modify values of the original application. Instead put plug-ins in a well known folder and load them directly or some other indirect loading mechanism. Modifying the state of the already installed application is very challenging for the original application to manage.